# How to delete Duplicate Characters from a given region in String?(given that we have the buffer from which we read the string from)

Tags: string, scala, duplicates

I am currently doing, my assignment from programming at first year of studies. We are given variables var buffer, marker, cursor, paste and our task is to read a certain area of the buffer, and in that area remove any duplicate characters, and paste that area into buffer again so that it is updated. 
    Bear in mind that I am performing tests(J-Unit), on my program and depending on how many it passes I get adequate mark. This function currently did not pass any of the tests. Here is the code:

```
**class** Buffer(s: String) {

  import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder



  private var buffer: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s)
  private var cursor: Int = 0 private var marker: Int = 0
  private var paste: String = ""
  private def end: Int = buffer.length              
  private def lwr: Int = Math.min(marker, cursor)
  private def upr: Int = Math.max(marker, cursor)

  def dd() {

    var MarkerToCursor = ""
    var CursorToMarker = ""
    var x = ""
    var y = ""

     //function whcih higlists a certain and then given that reads in characters of the buffer
    if(marker < cursor ){
      for(x <- marker until cursor)
        MarkerToCursor = MarkerToCursor + buffer.charAt(x)
        MarkerToCursor.toString
        x = MarkerToCursor.distinct

    //inserting the highlated area with the string into the buffer and updating it

         buffer = new StringBuilder(getString.substring(0, marker) + y+ getString.substring(cursor, end))
cursor = marker  + x.length      
      }
    else{

     // the same function as the one above except the region consists of charcyters from marker up to cursor.Eveyrything else is the same          
      for(x <- cursor until marker)
        CursorToMarker = CursorToMarker + buffer.charAt(x)
        CursorToMarker.toString
    y = CursorToMarker.distinct

     buffer = new StringBuilder(getString.substring(0, cursor) +y + getString.substring(marker, end))
marker = cursor  + y.length      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `input.drop(from) + input.substring(from, to).distinct + input.drop(to)`

Comment: getString combined with a method substring(x,y) gets a string between two variables (x,y) (the read in string string is part of thebuffer). Is that what you wanted to know?  Btw it compiles in my program although the thing which I've posted is part of a bigger program, so that's what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dima says in the comments, the logic for this is straightforward.

```
def removeDuplicatesInRange(str: String, start: Int, end: Int): String =
  str.take(start) + str.slice(start, end).distinct + str.drop(end)
```

Note that this creates a new string from the old, rather than using `var` or updating data in-place. Avoiding mutable data like this is one of the key elements of functional programming, which is the main focus of the Scala language.